# Describing the symmetries: $AAa, AaA, aAA$ of a string.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, formal-languages

Suppose I'm dealing with strings of symbols $S = AAa$ where $A = aaa$ and that in order to describe the permutations $AaA, aAA$, I'm indexing the symbols as they occur (left-to-right works): $S_1 = A_2 A_3 a_4$.  If I now consider all permutations of indexed symbols on the right of "$=$" (essentially all permutations of $\{2,3,4\}$, then there are many uninteresting ones such as $A_3 A_2a_4$.

Can these uninteresting permutations be filtered out while still retaining a group structure?  Or is there another way to view the symmtries:
$AAa$, $AaA$, $aAA$?  The method must apply to longer strings as well.

Comment: Could you give a precise mathematical definition of "uninteresting ones"?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: If the group of permutations $S_n$ acts on the strings of length $n$, the uninteresting permutations $\sigma$ with respect to the string $s$ seem to be those $\sigma$ such that $\sigma s = s$.

Comment: @AlexM. yes those that, when the index is dropped, result in a non-change of the underlying string.